# Calling multiple DAO from a single servlet

Tags: servlets, ejb

does anyone know how to create object from mulitple data access object and call their method. When i create object from only one DAO and call their method then it works perfect but with multiple it throws null pointer exception,

[image: here is the screen shot of my code]

and here's the error i am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at front.Home.processRequest(Home.java:70) at front.Home.doGet(Home.java:97) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114) at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: You must add the @EJB annotation to each member variable you want to inject...

Comment: screenshot of the code... priceless :)

Comment: @tibtof Copy-pasting code is obviously bad practice ;)

Answer (score 3):

Annotations are only applied to a single field, class or method, so you should annotate all your dependencies separately:

```
@EJB private CategoryDAO categoryDAO;
@EJB private GoldDAO goldDAO;
@EJB private ForexDAO forexDAO;
```